# GCP VM Auto Stop and Start setup using GCP Instance schedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to setup an auto stop/start of some of my VMs in GCP and I already have an VM admin permission but when adding a VM to a instance schedule created I'm getting below error:

Compute Engine System service account service-5424xxxxxxx@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com needs to have [compute.instances.start,compute.instances.stop] permissions applied in order to perform this operation.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the service **service-5424xxxxxxx@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com** does not have a role that contains the permissions **compute.instances.start** and **compute.instances.stop**.

The following roles contain that permission:

- **Compute Instance Admin** - roles/compute.instanceAdmin
- **Compute Instance Admin (v1)** - roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1

Use the Google Cloud Console GUI to add the desired role or use the CLI:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding REPLACE_WITH_PROECT_ID \
--member "serviceAccount:service-5424xxxxxxx@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role "roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1"
```

Of course, use the correct service account email address.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. BTW, what is the difference between roles/compute.instanceAdmin vs roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1?

Because as far as I know, I already have roles/compute.instanceAdmin but not v1.

Comment: @ZeroKnowledge Those are Google managed roles and their permissions are updated from time to time by Google. You can list the permissions that a role has using **gcloud iam roles describe**. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/describe You can also check the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I followed these instructions and successfully adding the Compute Instance Admin (v1) privileges to my service account. However, I'm getting the same error even after adding the privileges. Any tips on what else to try? Could it be that the instance I am trying to assign to the schedule is currently running? Can I only add stopped instances to the schedule?

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this and wondering why this is not working when they have given Cloud Scheduler Admin /Compute Admin/Compute Instance Admin (beta)/Compute Instance Admin (v1) to the user through Google Cloud IAM, it is because you have to give these priveleges to service-RANDOMNUMBERXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com, where as you have given these privileges to RANDOMNUMBERXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. The "service-" at the beginning matters.

To achieve this, refer to @John-Hanley 's answer above